# Spring data jpa - field that has all the possible values of a table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA, I have a table which represents an enum value, and a corresponding entity that I want that one of its field will be 'all the possible values the enum can have', i.e. a field `possibleValues` that will be a select all on the other table. Preferably I don't want to have a relationship like `@ManyToMany` since:

1. It will always be a select all, I don't want to save to the database all the options and update them each time the enum values table changes.
2. I am going to have several enums, so for each enum create another many-to-many is less than ideal.

I've tried to find something like `@Formula` that will let me select all the values from another table, but it doesn't seem to work:

```java
@Transient
@Formula("select e.name from EnumTable e")
private List<String> possibleValues;
```

results in `possibleValues` always being null, and if I remove the `@Transient` I have to define the relationship between the two entities.

Comment: why do you need a table for enums? you can have it as part static values in your codebase.

Comment: They are not strictly enums like in code, it's a list of possible values with more data, plus they have i18n attributes.

Comment: In that case prefer adding it as an Entity cause hibernate is ignoring `Formula` as it is marked as `Transient`

Comment: What do you mean adding it as an entity? If it's a property `List<EnumEntity>` in the class, I still need to either define a relationship or make it `@Transient`. I need this list to _always_ contain all the possible values of `EnumEntity`

Comment: Why should this be even part of your entity? If you need it to display in an HTML form, just retrieve it and put it in a collection, don't try to shoehorn this into your entity as it simply doesn't belong there.

Comment: @apines to make `Formula` work this should be an entity. You need to define relationship between `SolidEntity` and `EnumEntity` and to add it to multiple entities then use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

For Enum value in database, I recommend using string (for object, you can use JSON to convert first before store and covert back after retrieve )

Comment: Can you please elaborate why? And also, how does it solve the problem?

Comment: any object can be convert to JSON string and then store the string into database, when you retrieve out JSON string, you can convert it back to object. of course, you need maybe another column to indicate the actual type e.g. book object etc.

Comment: I still don't understand how this solves the original question - how does it help you to use `@Formula` in order to retrieve all the entities?

Comment: it's not related to the @Formula, it's more a generic solution.

Comment: Ok, so how does it solve the problem? How will I get all the possible values?